# How to declog coffee maker clogged by milk

Tags: coffee, cleaning, milk

I have a coffee maker which I used milk in it rather than water. Now milk has clogged its tubes as shown here:

[image: coffee maker]

Can anybody help me with a simple and easy trick to clean and declog the coffee maker tubes? Thanks =)

---

Make and model

[image: make and model]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you ran milk though the machine you cooked a lot of fat and protein into the components, which ***isn't*** good. The only "easy" thing I could recommend is to try to run some clear vinegar through it, the acidity may break down the milk residue and clear the machine.

The only other way to get it working isn't as easy as it requires manually removing the residue using brushes. Inter-dental brushes are thin and bendable, you should be able to get them into those holes on the top picture. If you can get at the heating element with an old toothbrush that would be good too. Other than that the only thing I could think to try is a complete tear-down of the coffee machine, which may or may not be something within your skills or worth your time. Just remember to unplug it before you attempt any invasive repairs!

Answer (score 4):

Milk Line Cleaner is a thing - its intended to clean milk pipes in automatic espresso machines.

[image: From their website]

https://segafredo.co.nz/shop/cleaning-supplies/cafetto-milk-line-cleaner/

Downside, this is a liquid which is mixed at 1:25 with water, and is then pumped through the lines/pipes by a dedicated cleaning cycle built into the espresso machine.

If your lines are clogged completely, this may not work very well, and could risk damage to any pump or impeller drive.

> A better idea might have been to pour your warmed milk straight into the filter from above.  It wouldn't be dripped, but the filter and basket and jug would be easier to clean.  Given milk's nature, you would have to clean it all immediately once the milk has dripped out into the jug.